# Failed to register the Ethereum service::ethash is only supported as a historical component of already merged networks

Tags: go-ethereum

When I am trying to create private ethereum using geth. I get this error. I followed the below commands in Ubuntu 22.04.

1. geth --datadir node1/ account new
2. Created genesis.json file
3. sudo geth --datadir . init genesis.json # successful
4. bootnode --genkey=boot.key
5. bootnode --nodekey=boot.key -verbosity 7 -addr 10.13.2.94:30310  # got enode of bootnode
6. sudo geth --nousb --datadir=$pwd --keystore ./keystore/ --networkid 51889 --syncmode 'full' --port 30333 --miner.gasprice 0 --miner.gaslimit 0x8000000 --miner.etherbase '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001' --http --http.addr 'localhost' --http.port 8545 --http.api admin,eth,miner,net,txpool,personal,web3 --bootnodes 'enode://126e9638e4ae38a73ea2a159eb1c480d3e9fa7a987c12015ce273bee7b5a35efbe9e44d8dee933ee474f797b46dc796eecab078c81b82584d692e869e5aa0a42@10.13.2.94:0?discport=30310' --http.corsdomain '*' --mine --allow-insecure-unlock --unlock "0xcbE683CEB094470AB3A2327ad908c0A9A110A407" --password acct_pswd.txt

When I run I get the error below.

[image]

My genesis file is

```
  {
  "config": {
    "chainId": 1337,
    "homesteadBlock": 0,
    "eip150Block": 0,
    "eip155Block": 0,
    "eip158Block": 0,
    "byzantiumBlock": 0,
    "constantinopleBlock": 0,
    "petersburgBlock": 0,
    "istanbulBlock": 0,
    "berlinBlock": 0,
    "londonBlock": 0
  },
  "alloc": {"0x9Be30a8Afa0E9A35F99B7Bce5Be2002059f9FC7C":{
            "balance":"11111111111111111111111111111111"
        },
        "0xD62a66F1d79C4C24515D5Fe32f87F20bDaBf5993":{
            "balance":"22222222222222222222222222222222"
        }
   },
  "coinbase": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "difficulty": "0x20000",
  "extraData": "",
  "gasLimit": "470000000000",
  "nonce": "0x0000000000000042",
  "mixhash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "timestamp": "0x00"
}
```

This private network has only 2 nodes.

I tried the following commands from online to resolve the issue :

```
 geth db metadata
```

Output has Fatal: Could not open database: open /.ethereum/geth /chaindata: no such file or directory

```
sudo geth --datadir node1 removedb
```

Deletes database successfully

```
 geth db metadata --datadir node1
```

Fatal: Could not create protocol stack: open /node1/geth/LOCK: permission denied

I tried uninstall and install ethereum. But still error persists.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you share the genesis file? Are you using Proof of Work consensus?

Comment: I shared my genesis file in question.

Comment: As of release v1.12.0, geth no longer support ethash as a consensus engine. Ethash has been removed from Geth v1.12. You can still create already-merged networks based on ethash (essentially merged-in-genesis == totalTerminalDifficulty and totalTerminalDifficultyPassed set), but for that you also need a beacon network.

Clique for now is functional but will also be dropped soon.

You should look into settig up private networks based on PoS.